# Blade Tempting Within @include("view")

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible for Blade's Engine to work within a view that is `@include()` from an extended view?

In my example i have an `index.blade.php` which `@extends` a `default.blade.php` master template. Within this **Default** template i include a number of other views. One of these views requires me to display some dynamic data which is passed to `default.blade.php` via a view composer. Within these views, Blade doesn't seem to work. All i get is flat text `{{ $var }}` with no processing.

Comment: Are you sure that your files are named with the .blade.php extension? If the blade ext is missing, blade will never be called to parse your view.

Comment: Yeah its called `_project.blade.php`

Comment: You can pass variables to @include

Comment: The fact that `{{ $var }}` is not processed, means that there's something wrong with blade. Or your file in particular.